# CSS hover recursively on all child elements

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to change the background-color attribute on ALL child elements of root on hover.  I have tried the following:

```
.app_setting *:hover { background-color: yellow; }

*:hover { background-color: yellow; }

html *:hover {background-color: yellow; }

<html class="parent">
</html>

.parent *:hover {background-color: yellow; }
```

I have also tried these links:

[CSS for hover that includes all child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137449/css-for-hover-that-includes-all-child-elements)

[CSS :hover to affect all child divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348332/css-hover-to-affect-all-child-divs)

The above seems to only affect and change the background-color of `<a>` tags.  Besides using javascript or assigning each element to a specific class is their another way to do this using CSS?

EDIT:

Fiddle deleted as this is a homework assignment and I do not want to share code BUT,

The fiddle DOES change child elements background-color attribute with

```
body *:hover {
    background-color: yellow;

}
```

as it is expected to.  ***But when opened in an HTML doc background-color is only applied to `<a>` tags.*** I have tried with the same effect in Firefox and Chrome.

Above problem was simple just needed to add a valid doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: On IE6 hover only works on `<a>` (anchor) elements. I hope you aren't using IE6?

Comment: I am using chrome and firefox and IE 11

Comment: Can you post a simple demo to show this 'not working,' that way we can see what *is* happening and offer suggestions? One of the answers suggests using `:hover *` to style the descendants of the hovered elements, but your question implies you want to style the hovered-element (and its ancestors, or more correctly 'all the hovered elements' as CSS lacks a parent-selector) with `*:hover`. So I'm not sure, now, what you're asking. Or how it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated with fiddle above.  Strangely it DOES work in a fiddle but does not work when opened in a HTML doc.  It acts the same when opened in different browsers.

Comment: @DavidThomas I have updated my question, any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put a hover on every element on the page.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLH3s/1/)

```
body *:hover{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

**Edit:**

As was pointed out in the comments, looks like what was really looked for here was how to apply a change to child elements on hover. While the code above is technically correct for that (will apply a red border to all children of the body tag, I think Smeegs has a more suitable answer below:

From Smeegs

```
.rootclass:hover *{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Where `.rootclass` is the parent class you want all children to be affected by on hover.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24496116/1174118

Comment: using that code exactly does not work. It only puts the border styling on the a tags.

Comment: Hmm strange, I mean it makes sense that would work.  I will add a fiddle of my site.

Comment: Well that DOES work on jsfiddle but does not when I open the html doc directly.

Comment: I believe the challenge is to apply hover to a particular element and all its children

Comment: Good point @patcapozzi , I added a note on that as well as a reference to smeegs answer below, perhaps the OP will swap accepted answers.

Answer (score 6):

I believe what you're looking for is something like

```
.rootclass:hover *{
    background-color: green;
}
```

if you want to only do direct descendents, make sure to use `>` instead of space, like so.

```
.rootclass:hover > *
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29fx8/)

When you hover over any part of the parent div, the background changes for every child element of that div.

Comment: what element would rootclass be assigned to?

Comment: Whatever you meant by `root`, I believe in your question you mentioned `.app_setting` so replace `rootclass` with `app_setting`

Comment: I added a fiddle to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to set a `:hover` effect to every child element you can use the syntax:

```
.app_setting :hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

if you want every child on any level to have the hovering effect.

Or you can use:

```
.app_setting > :hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

if you want only direct childs to have the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`.app_settings:hover *{ }`

as pointed out by Smeegs,
or if you want to set different backgrounds to different childs, you use the syntax:

`.app_settings:hover .childclass1{}`

`.app_settings:hover #child2id{}`

NOTE that if your elements already have a background-color set, you might have to use !important